# Юнит-тестирование в геймдеве при наличии сильных зависимостей

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, xna, monogame

Есть класс `TextureRegion2D`, который представляет собой прямоугольный фрагмент текстуры и принимает в конструкторе экземпляр `Texture2D` текстуры, на которой расположен этот фрагмент.

```
public class TextureRegion2D
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public Texture2D Texture { get; }

    public TextureRegion2D(string name, Texture2D texture)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            Name = name;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("The name of the texture region can not be null or an empty string.", nameof(name));

        Texture = texture ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(texture));
    }
}
```

Для юнит-тестирования данного класса необходимо иметь экземпляр класса `Texture2D`, который очень проблематично создать, т. к. для его создания необходимо создать экземпляр игры, проинициализировать графический адаптер и только тогда инстанцировать объект типа `Texture2D`, что очень дорого и долго в рамках юнит-тестирования.

В качестве путей разрешения ситуации я вижу два пути:

1. Не тестировать конструкторы и методы данного класса вовсе. Что плохо, потому что в конструкторе присутствует логика проверки аргументов на валидность, которую хотелось бы покрыть тестами.
2. Создать базовый `internal` конструктор, который будут вызывать публичные, в котором можно будет параметрами отключить проверку тех или иных аргументов.

   ```
   internal TextureRegion2D(string name, Texture2D texture, bool checkName, bool checkTexture)
   {
       if (!checkName || (checkName && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)))
           Name = name;
       else
           throw new ArgumentException("The name of the texture region can not be null or an empty string.", nameof(name));

       if (!checkTexture || (checkTexture && texture != null))
           Texture = texture;
       else
           throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(texture));
   }
   public TextureRegion2D(string name, Texture2D texture)
       : this(name, texture, true, true) { }
   ```

Каким путем лучше пойти в данной ситуации?

**Обновлено:** конкретно для данной ситуации нашел решение через инициализацю графического адаптера без создания экземпляра игры, но вопрос остается актуальным - как в общем случае тестировать методы, использующие типы из библиотек третьей стороны, но из-за своей атомарности не предполагающие разделения зависимостей с помощью паттерна `фабрика` или подобных ему?

Comment: а что конкретно вам надо тестировать в текстуре?

Comment: @tym32167, Если создать экземпляр `TextureRegion2D` с именем или текстурой, равной `null`, то при попытке отрисовки вылетит `NullReferenceException`, что не есть хорошо. По-сути, это единственное, что тестируется здесь.

Comment: то есть вам нужнен юнит тест, который проверит, что в класс попала текстура, а не указатель на null? для этого ав можете любую текстуру использовать. Сам механизм отрисовки или движок игры для этого наверное нет смысла запускать

Comment: @tym32167, в этом и была проблема - не было очевидной возможности создать экземпляр текстуры без создания и инициализации фреймворка игры (позже все-таки нашел способ, но не уверен, что в следующий раз все разрешится настолько же удачно). Что обычно делают в подобных ситуациях? Пишут internal-методы, которые вырезают не подлежащий тестированию функционал или избавляются от зависимостей с помощью всяких IMyDependencyProvider c моком поверх них?

Comment: ну тут наверное нет универсального способа. Если бы мне надо было запустить всю машину смерти ради одной текстуры, я бы подумал, что код у меня так себе, и постарался бы облегчить создание текстуры или попробовал пересмтреть мою архитектуру - но это я как кровавый энтерпрайник говорю, как это в геймдеве делается я без понятия, ес честно.